# list iterator + operator

Tags: c++, stdlist

```
// ((++currentEntry)--) is equivalent to (currentEntry + 1). Kind of.
menuEntries.insert((++currentEntry)--, newEntries.begin(), newEntries.end());
```

So I have the world's worst piece of code here. Is there a better way to do this?

When using '+ 1' I get this:

```
source/menu.cpp:146:37: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('list<menuEntry *>::iterator' (aka '_List_iterator<menuEntry *>') and
      'int')
                            menuEntries.insert(currentEntry + 1, ...
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
```

Comment: What do you mean "Kind of"? Why can't you just use (currentEntry + 1) instead?

Comment: you do have the worst piece of code

Comment: just use (currentEntry + 1), unless operator++ and operator-- have side-effects. Also, what the heck is menuEntries ?

Comment: @Gendolkari std::list iterators are not random-access, you can't add, you can only increment (btw, I think that wanting to do something like this is not uncommon :)

Comment: @Kiril: The iterator of a `list`  is not a random access operator.

Comment: @KennyTM - Argh, right .. Noted, thanks (: Anyway, Jookia never said it's a list, that's why I asked what is menuEntries.

Comment: @Kiril: It is right in the title :)

Comment: @KennyTM and @Jookia - Argh .. sorry about that....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not split into multiple lines:

```
iterator nextEntry = currentEntry;
menuEntries.insert( ++nextEntry, newEntries.begin(), newEntries.end());
```

where `iterator` is iterator type for the list. Personally, I would probably pull the `++nextEntry` onto its own line for further clarity - but that is probably a subjective decision.

Comment: +1 from me, too (: If you don't want the `nextEntry` to exist after this `insert` for some reason, you could put these two lines into a inner scope.

Comment: I now have. "std::list<menuEntry*>::iterator nextEntry = (++currentEntry)--;" which is good. Thanks.

Comment: @Jookia: In this code it isn't better nicer than your original one. That `++x--` is still there...

Comment: Yes mine lacks the inc/dec - that is messy. Just the one increment thank you!

Comment: @Jookia: if I'm reading that right, doing `std::list<menuEntry*>::iterator nextEntry = (++currentEntry)--;` will (by the next line) leave you with an iterator to the same element as `currentEntry`. The whole reason for making another iterator is to change that one and leave the original untouched, making the inc/dec combo unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

How about a helper function:

```
template<class IterT>
IterT Next(IterT i)
{
  return ++i;
}
```

You could then replace `(++currentEntry)--` by `Next(currentEntry)`

**Edit:**
Or even better: If you use Boost see Rob's suggestion of [next and prior in the Utility library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#functions_next_prior)

Comment: Precisely. Boost provides [`next` and `prior` functions in its Utility library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#functions_next_prior). They work like `std::advance`, but they return a new value instead of modifying the input value.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks a lot for the comment, I'll add it to my answer if you don't mind. I vaguely remembered seeing something in Boost but could not find it (I was looking in the Iterator library)

Answer (score 0):

```
++currentEntry;
menuEntries.insert(currentEntry, newEntries.begin(), newEntries.end());
--currentEntry;
```

or

```
menuEntries.insert(++currentEntry, newEntries.begin(), newEntries.end());
--currentEntry;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse iterators, for example:

```
myList.insert(myList.rbegin(), newEntries.begin(), newEntries.end())
```

would add the new items to the end.

Of course, whether this works for you depends on how you are using your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to affect your currentEntry iterator, and you want to insert the member after currentEntry, currentEntry + 1 is the best bet.

Comment: Help appreciated but it's for an std::list.